# WSL Ubuntu Cargo Rust openssl environment variables not set

Tags: rust, openssl, windows-subsystem-for-linux, rust-cargo

I've already tried installing and reinstalling pkg-config and libssl-dev. It appears as though the openssl environment variables are not being set on installation. All other posts suggest to install pkg-config and libssl-dev but that doesn't work here. Any suggestions?

I'm thinking it has something to do with WSL as it works just fine on a full Ubuntu install.

```
   Compiling openssl-sys v0.9.61
The following warnings were emitted during compilation:

warning: build/expando.c:4:24: error: pasting "RUST_VERSION_OPENSSL_" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
warning:     4 | #define VERSION2(n, v) RUST_VERSION_##n##_##v
warning:       |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
warning: build/expando.c:5:23: note: in expansion of macro ‘VERSION2’
warning:     5 | #define VERSION(n, v) VERSION2(n, v)
warning:       |                       ^~~~~~~~
warning: build/expando.c:10:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘VERSION’
warning:    10 | VERSION(OPENSSL, OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER)
warning:       | ^~~~~~~

error: failed to run custom build command for `openssl-sys v0.9.61`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/home/andrew/noaa-weather/target/debug/build/openssl-sys-807532aa820f3352/build-script-main` (exit code: 101)
  --- stdout
  cargo:rustc-cfg=const_fn
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=X86_64_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNU_OPENSSL_LIB_DIR
  X86_64_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNU_OPENSSL_LIB_DIR unset
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OPENSSL_LIB_DIR
  OPENSSL_LIB_DIR unset
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=X86_64_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNU_OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR
  X86_64_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNU_OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR unset
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR
  OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR unset
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=X86_64_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNU_OPENSSL_DIR
  X86_64_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNU_OPENSSL_DIR unset
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OPENSSL_DIR
  OPENSSL_DIR unset
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OPENSSL_NO_PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OPENSSL_STATIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OPENSSL_DYNAMIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALL_STATIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALL_DYNAMIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_PATH
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=SYSROOT
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OPENSSL_STATIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OPENSSL_DYNAMIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALL_STATIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALL_DYNAMIC
  cargo:rustc-link-search=native=/usr/local/lib
  cargo:rustc-link-lib=ssl
  cargo:rustc-link-lib=crypto
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OPENSSL_STATIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OPENSSL_DYNAMIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALL_STATIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALL_DYNAMIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_PATH
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
  OPT_LEVEL = Some("0")
  TARGET = Some("x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu")
  HOST = Some("x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu")
  CC_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu = None
  CC_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu = None
  HOST_CC = None
  CC = None
  CFLAGS_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu = None
  CFLAGS_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu = None
  HOST_CFLAGS = None
  CFLAGS = None
  CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
  DEBUG = Some("true")
  CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FEATURE = Some("fxsr,sse,sse2")
  running: "cc" "-O0" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-g" "-fno-omit-frame-pointer" "-m64" "-I" "/usr/local/include" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-E" "build/expando.c"
  cargo:warning=build/expando.c:4:24: error: pasting "RUST_VERSION_OPENSSL_" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
  cargo:warning=    4 | #define VERSION2(n, v) RUST_VERSION_##n##_##v
  cargo:warning=      |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
  cargo:warning=build/expando.c:5:23: note: in expansion of macro ‘VERSION2’
  cargo:warning=    5 | #define VERSION(n, v) VERSION2(n, v)
  cargo:warning=      |                       ^~~~~~~~
  cargo:warning=build/expando.c:10:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘VERSION’
  cargo:warning=   10 | VERSION(OPENSSL, OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER)
  cargo:warning=      | ^~~~~~~
  exit code: 1

  --- stderr
  thread 'main' panicked at '
  Header expansion error:
  Error { kind: ToolExecError, message: "Command \"cc\" \"-O0\" \"-ffunction-sections\" \"-fdata-sections\" \"-fPIC\" \"-g\" \"-fno-omit-frame-pointer\" \"-m64\" \"-I\" \"/usr/local/include\" \"-Wall\" \"-Wextra\" \"-E\" \"build/expando.c\" with args \"cc\" did not execute successfully (status code exit code: 1)." }

  Failed to find OpenSSL development headers.

  You can try fixing this setting the `OPENSSL_DIR` environment variable
  pointing to your OpenSSL installation or installing OpenSSL headers package
  specific to your distribution:

      # On Ubuntu
      sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
      # On Arch Linux
      sudo pacman -S openssl
      # On Fedora
      sudo dnf install openssl-devel

  See rust-openssl README for more information:

      https://github.com/sfackler/rust-openssl#linux
```

Comment: What version of openssl did you install? it may be related to https://github.com/sfackler/rust-openssl/issues/1448#issuecomment-814218122

Comment: So, was an actual solution ever reached here? If so, can you share?

Answer (score 0):

[As commented](https://github.com/sfackler/rust-openssl/issues/1448#issuecomment-1159102087), OpenSSL `3.x` may be incompatible, but you can install the latest `1.1.1` version:

```bash
# latest March 2023 release 

ENV OPENSSL_DIR="/opt/openssl"

curl "https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1t.tar.gz" \
  --output "/tmp/openssl.tar.gz"
mkdir --parent "/tmp/openssl"
tar \
  --extract \
  --file="/tmp/openssl.tar.gz" \
  --strip=1 \
  --directory="/tmp/openssl"
( \
  cd "${TMP}/openssl" \
  ./config \
    --prefix="/opt/openssl" \
    --openssldir="/opt/openssl" \
  make && make install \
)
```

Note:

- 1.1.1 is [actively maintained](https://www.openssl.org/news/vulnerabilities-1.1.1.html), and as of March 2023 [reported vulnerabilities have dropped off](https://www.cvedetails.com/version-list/217/383/1/Openssl-Openssl.html)
- `3.x` versions [have had recent vulnerabilities](https://www.openssl.org/news/vulnerabilities-3.0.html#y2023)

So it may also be more prudent sticking with `1.1.1` for now if you can.